# Control java application from another java application

Tags: java

I have two java applications. Let's call them master and slave. I want run some slaves from master and invoke slave methods from master. I have idea how to do it with sending and parsing udp messages through sockets. But i curios, maybe there more simpler approach to invoke slave methods? Ideally it like

```
getSlave(index).invokeMethod(args)
```

Comment: you can look at `RMI` (remote method invocation). That's a way for java apps to communicate over network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into RMI?  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/

Provides method for remotely calling methods from another application on same or other JVM.